# Why isn't my code going through all the lines in my .txt

Tags: python

```
for line in open('list.txt'):
    string1, string2 = line.split(':')

print(string1)
```

list.txt contains a list of different strings divided like this: string1:string2 .

How do I get it to print string1 from all of the lines?

Comment: indent second line by 4 spaces.

Comment: Corrected it to the correct indentation.

Comment: you are almost there, just indent your code

Comment: Possibly you want your `print` statement to be inside the loop? (in which case, it should be more indented). Other than that, I can't tell what you're asking.

Comment: @khelwood that fixed it lol, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Print string1 for each line

```
for line in open('list.txt'):
    string1, string2 = line.split(':')
    print(string1)
```

2) Store lines inside an array, print the array

```
content = []
for line in open('list.txt'):
    string1, string2 = line.split(':')
    content.append(string1)

print(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, your issue is with the indentation of the print function. Indent it to bring it inside the loop. As an alternative, since you're not really interested in string2, you could try the following to print just the first element after splitting the line.

```
for line in open('list.txt'):
    print line.split(':')[0]
```